# org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped

Tags: cdi, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

The CDI SessionScoped is working great until the cluster server is restarted. Encounter "ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303"(as below) when try to access. But the error go away after redeploy through WebLogic Server Admin Console. I suspect it has something to do with the WebLogic start up configuration. Any idea on this?

Error

> WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type
> javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped javax.el.ELException:
> /index.xhtml: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type
> javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
> at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
> at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
> Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No
> active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
> at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:95)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:178)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
> at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:761)
> Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

SessionCDI.java

```
package dev;

@javax.inject.Named
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class SessionCDI implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected String attr1;

    public SessionCDI() {
        this.attr1 = "SessionCDI new";
    }

    @javax.annotation.PostConstruct
    public void PostConstruct() {
        this.attr1 = "SessionCDI PostConstruct";
    }

    public String getAttr1() {
        return attr1;
    }

    public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
        this.attr1 = attr1;
    }

}
```

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions">
<h:body>
    <p>sessionCDI: #{sessionCDI.attr1}</p>
</h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Version

- WebLogic Server: 12.2.1.0.0
- web-app: 3.1
- CDI beans: 1.1